# C Programming: How can I get parent directory?

Tags: c, directory

In my `pathto.c` I want to open parent directory

```
static void list_dir (const char * dir_name)
{
    DIR * d;
    struct dirent *e;
    
    d = opendir ("dir_name/..");


    if (d == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open dircetory");
    }
}
```

but I got "Cannot open directory"

How can I call `opendir` to open parent directory?

Comment: You are passing a parameter named `dir_name` to your function, but you're not using it. Instead, you are looking for a directory literally named `dir_name`. Is that what you want? Or do you want to look for the parent directory of whatever the caller of `list_dir()` passes in?

Comment: @GregHewgill, I want the parent directory of whatever list_dir() passed in. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to append `/..` to the value of `list_dir` before calling `opendir()`. For example, you could do it like this:

```
char parent[200];
snprintf(parent, sizeof(parent), "%s/..", dir_name);
d = opendir(parent);
```